# Download and then Print PDF File in AngularJS not working on IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf

What I need is pdf file that is generated from back end to show in new tab in print mode. I implement one solution that is working for FF but not working on IE. Is there maybe some 'hack' for IE for this to work?

```
Service.downloadPdf(inputObject, scope.reportType).then(function (data) {
                                var file = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});  //pdf
                                var pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                                var printwWindow = $window.open(pdfUrl);
                                printwWindow.print();
                            });
```

I can see console error for IE only:

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'print' of undefined or null reference
```

Comment: can you check with window.open(pdfUrl);?

Comment: No it is same, no difference.

Answer (score -1):

```
then(function (data) {
var blob = new Blob([data.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.src = blobUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

}